# Construct a df such that every number within a range gets value 'A' assigned when knowing the start and end of the range values that belong to 'A'

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
In[285]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B'], 'Start': [1,6], 'End': [4,12]})

In [286]: df
Out[286]: 
  Name  Start  End
0    A      1   4
1    B      6   12
```

Now I would like to construct the dataframe as follows:

```
   Name  Number 
0     A       1
1     A       2
2     A       3
3     A       4
4     B       6
5     B       7
6     B       8
7     B       9
8     B       10
9     B       11
10    B       12
```

My biggest struggle is in getting the 'Name' column right. Is there a smart way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do `pd.concat` on a list comprehension:

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame({'Number': np.arange(s,e+1)})
             .assign(Name=n)
           for n,s,e in zip(df['Name'], df['Start'], df['End']))
```

Output:

```
   Number Name
0       1    A
1       2    A
2       3    A
3       4    A
0       6    B
1       7    B
2       8    B
3       9    B
4      10    B
5      11    B
6      12    B
```

---

**Update:** As commented by @rafaelc:

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame({'Number': np.arange(s,e+1), 'Name': n}) 
             for n,s,e in zip(df['Name'], df['Start'], df['End']))
```

works just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I tried before that didn't work. Maybe `[n]` instead of `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Let us do it with this example (with 3 names):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C'], 'Start': [1,6,18], 'End': [4,12,20]})
```

You may create the target columns first, using list comprehensions:

```
name = [row.Name for i, row in df.iterrows() for _ in range(row.End - row.Start + 1)]
number = [k for i, row in df.iterrows() for k in range(row.Start, row.End + 1)]
```

And then you can create the target DataFrame:

```
expanded = pd.DataFrame({"Name": name, "Number": number})
```

You get:

```
   Name  Number
0     A       1
1     A       2
2     A       3
3     A       4
4     B       6
5     B       7
6     B       8
7     B       9
8     B      10
9     B      11
10    B      12
11    C      18
12    C      19
13    C      20
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd take advantage of `loc` and `index.repeat` for a vectorized solution.

```
base = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['End'] - df['Start'] + 1), ['Name', 'Start']]

base['Start'] += base.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
```

---

```
  Name  Start
0    A      1
0    A      2
0    A      3
0    A      4
1    B      6
1    B      7
1    B      8
1    B      9
1    B     10
1    B     11
1    B     12
```

Of course we can rename the columns and reset the index at the end, for a nicer showing.

```
base.rename(columns={'Start': 'Number'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
   Name  Number
0     A       1
1     A       2
2     A       3
3     A       4
4     B       6
5     B       7
6     B       8
7     B       9
8     B      10
9     B      11
10    B      12
```